# Href links while navigating through pages is giving error 404

Tags: html, css

Navigating through the pages, the links are removing the repo name in the url and giving me an error 404. I am thinking it might have to do something with using absolute paths instead of relative paths. Any pointers on how to correct this issue? I also noticed that github pages is case sensitive so I will have to update that as well once I correct this issue.
Example of pathing error url removing repo name: https://joshuabentley.github.io/assets/html/progress.html

Using chrome developer tools, I tried updating some of the pathing links, worked for some of the Css files and images. Didn't correct the pathing errors.

Repo Link: [Link to repo](https://github.com/JoshuaBentley/GreatestAppEver)
Deployment Link: [Link to Deployed webpage](https://joshuabentley.github.io/GreatestAppEver/)

#Sample Code from one of my html files within a folder

```
<header>Weight Lifting Guide
    <p class="link">
      <a href="/index.html">Home</a>
    </p>
    <p class="link">
      <a href="/assets/html/nutrition.html">Calculator</a>
    </p>
    <p class="link">
      <a href="/assets/html/progress.html">Progress</a>
    </p>
    <p class="link">
      <a href="/assets/html/recipe.html">Recipes</a>
    </p>
  </header>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: updated, and apologies, first time posting to SO.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the `/` from `/assets/html/progress.html`

```
<header>Weight Lifting Guide
     <p class="link">
      <a href="/assets/html/progress.html">Progress</a>
    </p>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add `.` before link started  /assets/html/progress.html

> `./assets/html/progress.html`